# Print grid of columns wrapped to length

Tags: python, python-3.x, multidimensional-array, printing, formatting

I am trying to print a 2-dimensional list in a format that wraps the length of each column to the length of the longest word in that column (plus 2 spaces padding). Example of what I'm trying to achieve below:

```
t1      thing2   t3            t4
thing5  t6       thingymajig7  thing8
thing9  thing10
```

Currently, my code almost achieves this, but it keeps clipping off the last 'n' number of columns if there is a row with less than the max number of items in it. Example below:

```
t1      thing2
thing5  t6
thing9  thing10
```

This is the part of my code so far:

```
rows = [[thing1, thing2, thing3, t4], [t5, t6, thingymajig7, thing8], [thing9, thing10]]

widths = [max(len(item) for item in col) for col in zip(*rows)]

for r in rows:
    print("  ".join((item.ljust(width) for item, width in zip(r, widths))))
```

What do I need to add/change to stop it from removing incomplete columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be with this line:

`widths = [max(len(item) for item in col) for col in zip(*rows)]`

From the docs on zip: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip

> The iterator stops when the shortest input iterable is exhausted.

So each list in `rows` would have to be lengthened to the length of the longest list in `rows` for this script to work. You could achieve that with this:

```
rows = [['thing1', 'thing2', 'thing3', 't4'], ['t5', 't6', 'thingymajig7', 'thing8'], ['thing9', 'thing10']]

max_row_len = len(max(rows, key=len))

for row in rows:
  row_len = len(row)
  row.extend(['blank' for f in range(max_row_len - row_len)])

widths = [max(len(item) for item in col) for col in zip(*rows)]

for r in rows:
    print("  ".join((item.ljust(width) for item, width in zip(r, widths))))
```

You could then replace `'blank'` with `''`